# Followed guide on scaffolding with aldeed collections/autoforms, all selects are "x is not an allowed value"

Tags: meteor, scaffolding, meteor-autoform

Now the aldeed autoform example doesn't have provision for label when using:

```
{favoriteColor: {
type: String,
allowedValues: ['red', 'green', 'blue']
}}
```

but I inserted label: "the form question". Packages in question are collections2/autoforms from aldeed on github. This is my repo and the guide: https://github.com/janat08/corp && https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-speed-up-meteor-development-with-scaffolding-and-automatic-form-generation

Although I haven't tried removing the labels I'm not interested in doing that, as clearly the form must have the question while the mainstream example syntax has label: for values, there then must be a way to put a label onto the form rather than the values? I'd appreciate it if someone pointed what syntax to use if I wished to use radio instead of default dropdown.

The point of these two packages is to other than scaffolding the forms when creating schema to then also automate some of the routing or something.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read more about putting default field attributes in schema [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#putting-field-attribute-defaults-in-the-schema) as well as creating a custom template [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#creating-a-custom-template)

Comment: autoform: {
    rows: 10
  }

Instead Radial is what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that quickfield/forms or something don't work with custom schema as they would not work with anything other than simple schema which is what my freelancer translates to me. Go blindly follow a guide.

Comment: Not sure at which point my schema became a custom one but wtv. I'll just have a look through additional package expansions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the question is irrelevant as I haven't done any further testing, but I left off at the spaces being poorly put in transit (you put space in " " and it's missing in the form).